# What are the options for supporting camera stream on ios without publishing an app?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, webrtc

This may be off topic for SO, not sure where else to put it though.

I have a web application that utilizes the webrtc standard. This app is run purely in javascript. It gets a stream from a camera, and processes each frame in javascript. The problem, as everybody dealing with webrtc in browsers knows, is apple has decided to not yet support and implement the standard in their native browsers. We need this web application to be supported by apple products, and publishing an application in the apple store is not an option (this web app is a promotional thing, and is not planned on being up for very long, maybe a month or two, and has to be ready in a couple weeks). So what i'm wondering is what are my options for camera stream processing without publishing an app?

Here are the options i'm currently thinking:

1. Not even sure if this is possible, but grab a frame from the camera using the input tag, send it to a server which just pings it back where javascript can start processing it. The problem with this is i think that the user must click a button for every frame that gets sent up, so thats not real time and probably won't work.
2. I'm still looking into this, but piggy backing off an already published app. I came across people talking about using phonegap to support webrtc. Is this an application users can download from the app store? This seems the most promising at the moment. We would detect that the user is on an iphone when they go to the webpage, and direct them to the app store to download phonegap. I'm not sure exactly how phonegap works, but i'm hoping i would just be able to have my webpage open phonegap on the users phone and provide phonegap with the html and javascript that i would like to run.
3. tell the user to download the Bowser Browser which apparently supports webrtc. If bowser supports webrtc this might be a good choice, but the client wants this app to run whatever browser they are in i guess, and i had mentioned phonegap and they seem to like that best.

Is there a published app that can run in the background, where i could send it a message containing something i want from the device, like a frame from the camera or video stream from the camera, which it would then pass back to the browser? i'm pretty sure thats a huge security risk so probably not something, but thought i'd ask anyway.

ios is not usually a platform i work with, so i might be missing something that would be better than any of the above methods

Comment: ok, number two shows how much i know about ios. it appears that phonegap is not at all what i thought it was. It is not an app users download, but a development framework that allows you to make ios apps using html, javascript and css. So if i'm correct, then number 2 is not even an option...

Comment: If you want that your app works on any browser, and only bowser browser supports webrtc, then you are out of luck...

Comment: yeah, bowser looks like the only option on iphones, so i'll just add a link to bowser in the app store when a user is on an unsupported browser on iphone. hopefully apple decides to support the standard in the future

Comment: Too bad you had no time to publish an App, WebRTC frameworks exist on iOS and other platforms (JS/Android) like http://www.skylink.io for example.

Comment: yeah, we have a lot of different clients though, and we don't want to publish an app for only a month while a campaign is running, so we needed a solution that wouldn't involve publishing apps for every client. We went with a link to the bowser browser if the device was detected as an iphone, which seemed to make everyone happy enough. hopefully apple decides to implement webrtc in their webview someday so we don't have to direct all iphone users to a different browser